# Scipy fit complex multivariable function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am having trouble fitting data on a complex function (in the sense of having image in the complex plane) of two (real) variables.

My problem is that I'm unsure how to pass the variables, if I need to concatenate them in one single object (using the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function) ; and also, if I can fit the the data in one go, without separating and fitting separately the real and imaginary part.

Edit: after playing a bit with `curve_fit` it does seem that it take complex numbers in or functions in the complex plane. I guess that or I'll have to fit separately (I'm bothered about how to treat my two sets of fit parameters then, or lost information/precision in there) or using another tool.

Comment: The fitting functions in scipy work fine with any input, including complex, so long as a real number can be arrived at for the cost. Suggest you use one of the fmin*, where you explicitly calculate the cost.

Comment: Are you sure it works with complex objects? I get the following error when trying:

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
`

Comment: This is not too helpful, as I cannot see what you are doing.

Comment: I have d and a as my two real variables, r and i as the real and imaginary part of my data (meant to be fitted). And I'm running it as:


`def func3((var1,var2),amp,exp,spin):`
`return amp*var1**exp*N.exp(1j*spin*var2)`
`curve_fit(func3,(d,a),r+1j*i)`

Comment: Please check my edit to see if this is what you mean.